# Binary files structure for objects and structs in C++/Python

Tags: python, c++, binaryfiles

I have a simple (and maybe silly) question about binary data files. If a simple type is used (int/float/..) it is easy to imagine the structure of the binary file (a sequence of floats, with each float written using a fixed number of bytes). But what about structures, objects and functions ? Is there some kind of convension for each language with regards to the order in which the variables names / attributes / methods are written, and if so, can this order be changed and cusotomized ? otherwise, is there some kind of header that describes the format used in each file ?

I'm mostly interested in python and C/C++. When I use a pickled (or gzipped) file for example, python "knows" whether the original object has a certain method or attribute without me casting the unpickled object or indicating its type and I've always wondered how is that implemented. I didn't know how to look this up on Google because it may have something to do with how these languages are designed in the first place. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "use" a pickled file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called *serialization* - because it is about serializating your memory data structures into linear stream of bytes - files.

The basic algorithm is something like "iterate over all keys and values in a dict (or over all keys in a list) and print them into a file". But you have to specify a *format* first - if you store a string, how do you know when it ends? Well, you have to store its length first, or use some kind of end-of-string mark (like `"` in JSON).

Some serialization formats that are widely used for custom data are JSON, YAML, XML, MessagePack, Google Protocol Buffers...

For an idea how this works have a look for example at [msgpack spec](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md) or [Cap'n'Proto Encoding Spec](https://capnproto.org/encoding.html) (Cap'n'Proto is another serialization format, a bit low-level one).

For Python pickle there is [PEP 3154](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3154/) with protocol 4 specification and of course also a [source code of the picke module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/pickle.py).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation ! That clears it up..

Answer (score 1):

Binary files contain data.

There are a plethora of data layouts of binary files.  Some examples are JPEG, Executables, Word Processor, Raw Text and archive files.

A file *may* have an extension that *may* indicate the layout.  For example, a ".png" would would most likely follow the PNG format.  A "bin" or "dat" extension is to generic.  One could zip up files and name the archive with a "png" extension.

If there is no file extension or the OS doesn't store the type of a file, then the format of the file is based on discovery (or trying random formats).  Some file formats have integrity values in them to help verify correctness.  Knowing the integrity value and how it was calculated, can assist in classify the format type.  Again, there is no guarantee.

BTW, file formats are independent of the language to used to read them.  One could read a gzipped file using FORTRAN or BASIC.